# Getting rid of #! in angularjs ngRoute

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, ngroute

I'm working with Angularjs ngRoute  for SPA with Node.js as my backend, I have 3 pages in my website say:

- `localhost:8000/#!/`
- `localhost:8000/#!/red`
- `localhost:8000/#!/green`

By googling I found the way to get rid off `/**#!**/` and it worked fine only when a user has no intention to press F5 to reload a page. If reloaded, structure of my page becoming worse. What I mean, If a user pressed F5 when he/she is in `red.html` page, then `red.html` alone displayed instead of injecting the `red.html` content in **ng-View** Thats the nature of nodejs get request. Is there any ways to get rid off from this problem?

#### index.html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <p><a href="/">Main</a></p>
  <a href="/red">Red</a>
  <a href="/green">Green</a>

  <ng-view></ng-view>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
    app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
          templateUrl: "/main"
        })
        .when("/red", {
          templateUrl: "/red"
        })
        .when("/green", {
          templateUrl: "/green"
        })

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });

  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Injecting the HTML content where? `red.html` should be loaded inside `ng-view` whats the problem so and what is missing?

Comment: If reloaded red.html is not injecting inside ng-view . instead It display alone( display only red.htm with no html tag, head tag and so on)

Comment: If you reload this URL `localhost:8000/red` your configured route `.when("/red", ... ` should be loaded. There should be not suffix like `.html` in your URL. Whats the problem?

Comment: it's not really an answer to your question, but IMHO don't use ngRoute. Use ui-router (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead.

Comment: You have to configure server to account for the virtual directories when you use `html5mode`. Don't use same template path as page path or there is no way on server to differentiate

Comment: Why should I reload  localhost:8000/#!/red when I use    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);   The url itself will display  localhost:8000/red  @lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `node.js` with `express`, right? In that way just link all your application view routes to your `index.html` and put your partial views in an other subdirectory to avoid route conflicts:

```
//resources 
app.use("/js", express.static(__dirname + "/js"));
app.use("/img", express.static(__dirname + "/img"));
app.use("/css", express.static(__dirname + "/css"));

//different path for your partials to avoid route conflicts
app.use("/partials", express.static(__dirname + "/partials"));

//view routes
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

In that way all your routes:

- `localhost:8000/`
- `localhost:8000/red`
- `localhost:8000/green`

will point at your `index.html`. So your `$routeProvider` will be able to inject the view in the right way, while your `index.html` will be loaded every time.

#### Finally your route configuration should look like this:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
      templateUrl: "/partials/main.html"
    })
    .when("/red", {
      templateUrl: "/partials/red.html"
    })
    .when("/green", {
      templateUrl: "/partials/green.html"
    })

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

Comment: won't work when client side route templates use same path though

Comment: @charlietfl Oh yea, let me correct this.

Comment: HI lin, Clearly , What happens if i type localhost:3000/partials/red.html in chrome's URL and hit enter... My answer is red.html alone will be displayed as a page instead of injecting red.html's content to ng-view

Comment: @annapoorani Yep, but this could happend to all of your public resources. It's a normal case so and nothing abnormal. You can't prepend from accessing a public ressource even if you only allow it to load by an AJAX request. Your application routes doesnt point directly to your resource, in that way the user will not end on `/partials/red.html`. What do you expect?

Comment: Not only for public resources. but also for reload and F5 cases too is my exact problem

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, if you use html5-mode and hit F5, your server should serve not your red.html, but your index.html. That's because angular must be bootstrapped and parse your url to get right location.

EDIT: rules are:

1. if you call (or F5 or navigate directly) `http://localhost:8000`, then you must get index.html from server.
2. if you call (or F5 or navigate directly) `http://localhost:8000/red`, then you must get index.html from server too.

Bonus:

You should deliver your static content (images, css, html templates) from defined location like `http://localhost:8000/static/` or from another domain to have disambiguous paths to static files and your url-paths

Comment: I can't confess with your rule 2... if you call directly  http://localhost:8000/red   express will send red (static file) how do index will send over that get request

Comment: see answer from lin.